# Time complexity of simple recursive procedure with random variable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Considering this function:

```
function F1(n);
begin
  if n > 0 then
    for i := 0 to n do
      print(i);
      print(n - i);
    end for
    m := random(0, n - 1);   // tricky part
    F1(m);
  else
    print(n);
  end if
end function
```

I need to compute average time complexity of $F1$ procedure. Dominant operations are `print` calls. $random(d, g)$ returns random integer value from range $d, \cdots, g$.

So far I got this relation:

$$\begin{cases}T(0) = 1 \\ T(n) = T(m) + 2(n+1) \end{cases}$$

I believe it is correct so far. But I need to get rid of the $T(m)$ thing and make it dependant on something like $\underbrace{T(n-1)}_{\text{well, that'd be worst case}}$ or $T(\frac{n}{2})$ etc.

I was thinking in order to get rid of $m$ parameter perhaps I need to compute some sum, like:

$$m = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{n+1} = \frac{n}{2}$$

But I think the second sum is not really equivalent to the first sum, is it?

Regardless, my question is how to get rid of the $m$ parameter from my relation above.

Comment: For a very similar recursive algorithm, but one that actually does something practical instead of just printing lots of stuff, see [this paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/2003-Generating_Random_Factored_Numbers_Easily-SODA.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is slightly different:

Random always returns integer from $\{0,1, \cdots , n-2, n-1 \}$ interval. Probability is $\frac{1}{n}$ for each individual result.

$$\begin{cases}T(0) = 1 \\ T(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} T(m) + 2n + 2 \end{cases}$$

---

$$T(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}T(m) + 2n + 2 \quad \Bigg/\cdot n$$

$$\color{blue}{nT(n) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}T(m) + 2n^2 + 2n}$$

---

For $n = n -1$ we have:

$$(n-1)T(n-1) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-2}T(m) + 2(n-1)^2 + 2(n-1)$$

$$(n-1)T(n-1) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-2}T(m) + 2n^2 - 4n + 2 +2n - 2$$

$$\color{red}{(n-1)T(n-1) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-2}T(m) + 2n^2 - 2n}$$

---

Subtracting one from the another:

$$\color{blue}{nT(n)} - \color{red}{(n-1)T(n-1)} = \color{blue}{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}T(m) + 2n^2 + 2n} - \Bigg(\color{red}{\sum_{m=0}^{n-2}T(m) + 2n^2 - 2n}\Bigg)$$

$$nT(n) - (n-1)T(n-1) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}T(m) - \sum_{m=0}^{n-2}T(m) + 4n$$

$$nT(n) - (n-1)T(n-1) = T(n-1) + 4n$$

$$nT(n) = (n-1)T(n-1) + T(n-1) + 4n$$

$$nT(n) = nT(n-1) + 4n$$

---

Hence the recurrence relation is of the form:

$$\begin{cases} T(0) = 1 \\ \underbrace{n}_{a_{n}}T(n) = \underbrace{n}_{b_{n}}T(n-1) + \underbrace{4n}_{c_{n}} \end{cases}$$

---

Which can be further solved for example by applying method of summation factors:

$$T(n) = \frac{1}{S_{n}a_{n}} \Bigg(T_{0}S_{1}b_{1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}c_{k}\Bigg)$$

$$S_{n} = \frac{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-2}a_{n-1}}{b_{2}b_{3} \cdots b_{n-1}b_{n}} = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k}}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}b_{k}} = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}k} = \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)!n} = \frac{1}{n}$$

$$\Longrightarrow T(n) = \frac{1}{\frac{n}{n}}\Bigg(1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{4k}{k}\Bigg)$$

$$T(n) = 1 + 4\sum_{k=1}^{n}1$$

$$\underbrace{T(n) = 1 + 4n = O(n)}_{\text{average time complexity}}$$

---

WolframAlpha's string: `T(0) = 1, n*T(n) = n*T(n-1) + 4n`

Comment: Once you have $n T(n) = n T(n-1) + 4n$, can't you just divide by $n$ and say $T(n) = T(n-1) + 4$, so $T(n) = 4n + T(0) = 4n + 1$?

Comment: This produces the same result, didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $F_1(m)$ will ever get called is $\frac1{m+1}$. Here's why.

Whether $F_1(m)$ will get called or not is determined the first time that the random number we choose falls into the set $\{0, 1, \dots, m\}$. If it does not, then we call $F_1(m')$ for some $m'> m$, and the decision is simply postponed until another day. But if it does, then given that the random number falls into the set $\{0, 1, \dots, m\}$, the probability that it's $m$ is $\frac1{m+1}$: and if it's not $m$, we skip it.

Or to put it differently: if we ask "which of the numbers $\{0, 1, \dots, m\}$ is the first one we see returned from a call to `random`?" then until one of them *does* get returned, all of them remain possible, and so the answer is equally likely to be any of them, by symmetry. But $F_1(m)$ gets called exactly when $m$ is the first one on that list.

(Finally, if this still does not convince you - it's tricky to wrap your head around - then define $f_{m,n}$ to be the probability that $m$ ever gets called, starting from $n$. We'll have $f_{m,m+1} = \frac1{m+1}$, because the only way to ever call $m$ from $m+1$ is directly. In general, $$f_{m,n} = \frac1n + \frac1n f_{m,m+1} + \frac1n f_{m,m+2} + \dots + \frac1n f_{m,n-1},$$ and we can prove $f_{m,n} = \frac1{m+1}$ by induction on $n$.)

---

Now that we know this, we can compute the expected running time just by multiplying the number of `print` calls in $F_1(m)$, which is $2m+2$, by the probability that $F_1(m)$ is called, which is $\frac1{m+1}$. This product is $2$. So each of $F_1(0), \dots, F_1(n-1)$ contributes $2$ to the expected number of print calls, and $F_1(n)$ contains $2n+2$ more, for a total of $4n+2$ expected print calls. (Actually, it's $4n+1$ because $F_1(0)$ only includes one `print` call, not two. Whatever.) So the running time is $O(n)$.

Comment: Shouldn't we take into account set $\{ 0, 1, \cdots, m -1 \}$?

Comment: What do you mean, take into account?